# how to send Id in parameter to my server?

Tags: ios, iphone, swift

I have the json data with Name and id. im using the pickerview to view the json names. if user selected the name of json the name will appear in the textfield.but the problem is i need to send only the name of the Id
not name in parameter to server

here is my code

```
var Officerlist = [DistrictNames]()

func numberOfComponents(in pickerView: UIPickerView) -> Int {

        return 1
    }

    func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, numberOfRowsInComponent component: Int) -> Int {

        return Officerlist.count
    }

    func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, titleForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int) -> String? {

        return Officerlist[row].userName
    }

    func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, didSelectRow row: Int, inComponent component: Int) {

        let DistrictsName = Officerlist[row].userName
        DistrictUnit.text = DistrictsName
        return
    }
        func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, viewForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int, reusing view: UIView?) -> UIView {

        var label: UILabel

        if let view = view as? UILabel {
            label = view
        }else {
            label = UILabel()
        }

        label.textColor = UIColor.red
        label.textAlignment = .center
        label.font = UIFont(name: "Menlo-Regular", size: 18)
        label.text = Officerlist[row].userName

        return label
    }
let parameter = ["officerId": DistrictUnit.text!]
```

Comment: So your question is how you will get id for selected name?

Comment: yes bro i need to send only id in parameters

Comment: You can get it in your `didSelectRow` method with `Officerlist[row].id`

Comment: bro im not using tableview. i need to show name in textfield to user but i need to send selected name of id to server

Comment: bro how can i send in parameters let parameter = ["officerId": DistrictUnit.text!] only i need to send in parameters place of "officerID"

Comment: Check my answer below.

Comment: if user click username and the wants to selected but i only need to show user only name not userid but I need to send only userid to server in parameter

Comment: Update your `let parameter = ["officerId": selectedOfficeObj.id]` as per your need from my answer.

Comment: Thanks bro its working fine

Comment: Happy to help you.. :)

Comment: how can i follow you bro

Comment: There is not follow feature on SO.. :)

Comment: bro I can't ask another question. now its showing like this You have reached your question limit. and im new to stackoverflow

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a object outside your methods like:

```
var selectedOfficer: DistrictNames?
```

Then save it when user select any `row` in your `didSelectRow` method like:

```
selectedOfficer = Officerlist[row]
```

And your method will look like:

```
func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, didSelectRow row: Int, inComponent component: Int) {

    let DistrictsName = Officerlist[row].userName
    DistrictUnit.text = DistrictsName
    selectedOfficer = Officerlist[row]
}
```

Now when you are creating `parameter` you can get it like:

```
if let selectedOfficeObj = selectedOfficer {

    let parameter = ["officerId": selectedOfficeObj.id] 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You will get id in `didSelectRow` method

```
var index = Int() 

func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, didSelectRow row: Int, inComponent component: Int) {

            let districtsName = Officerlist[row].userName
            index = row // It gives selected row index
            index = Officerlist[row].id // It gives selected row Id
            DistrictUnit.text = districtsName
            return
        }
```

One more thing is `variable name` should start with small letter.